# Get value of json array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I have this jquery function that call a php function and return an array

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'json/orders.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { "value" : value },
    success: function(response) {

      ... how? ...

    }
});
```

This is the array :

```
[{"id":"560","price":"13.93","id_tax_rules_group":"1","reference":"CR332"}]
```

The array is always of 1 row...
How to get value that I use to update input value?

Thanks

Comment: Use `indexes` to get array elements `response[0].id`

Comment: where is your input box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your url `json/orders.php` I assume that your php page return a json object in the `response` so you could use **[`jsonParse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** or **[`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)** to parse it like :

```
response = $.parseJSON(response);
```

The get the attribute you want like :

```
response.id
response.price
response.reference
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var response = $.parseJSON('{"id":"560","price":"13.93","id_tax_rules_group":"1","reference":"CR332"}');

console.log(response.id, response.price, response.id_tax_rules_group);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```